# ShiftKey mouseEvent not recognizing key pressed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mouseevent

I have this function, on gogole maps circles, which was working perfect. But now it is no longer detecting the shiftKey, always returning false and I have no idea why.
Also tried `v=3`, `v=3.25`, `v=3.26`, `v=3.30`  and `v=3.31`.

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
 v=3.30&key=XXX&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"></script>


if (myCondittion) {
         myObj.addListener('click', function (event) {
            if (!shiftKeyPressed(event)) {
               //DoSOmething

            }
            } else {
               //DoSomethingElse
            }
         });
}


function shiftKeyPressed(event) {

   for (var key in event) {
      if (event[key] instanceof MouseEvent) {
         event["mouseEvent"] = event[key];
      }
   }

   var isPressed = event["mouseEvent"].shiftKey;
   console.log( event["mouseEvent"] );
   return isPressed;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to comment the reason for downvotes and close votes. NO way to help the community doin' that without explanation.

Comment: Is it happening in experimental version? Can you try different versions of API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Comment: @xomena I wasn't specifying the version, (which means experimental version according to documentation), and now I tried with the last release which is `v=3.26` and the problem still the same. The shift+Click is happening but the attribut for `shiftKey` always returns false.

Comment: The release version now 3.31, not 3.26. I guess you are reading the documentation translated to your language, it is outdated check always English version. If it doesn't work in 3.30, 3.31 and 3.32, that means this change happened between 3.29 and 3.30. I would suggest creating a sample at jsbin or jsfiddle and raise the issue with Google directly in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207).

Comment: The translation wasn't intentional, now it says indeed `3.30`. Thanks ! But the problem still the same, what I did, for now, was save the `onkeydown/up` of the shiftkey and check it when I click. But I rather not use a global variable =\ Only with google maps it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that I am also having this issue with shiftkey, altkey, and ctrlkey. I am on the experimental version and it was working just fine until about a week ago, when this was posted.

As a work around I created global variables:

```
var _keydownEvent;

var setKeydownEvent = function(e){
  _keydownEvent = e;
}

var getKeydownEvent = function(){
  return _keydownEvent;
}

app.setKeydownEvent = setKeydownEvent;
app.getKeydownEvent = getKeydownEvent;
```

Global listeners:

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
  app.setKeydownEvent(e);
});

$(window).bind('keyup', function(e){
  app.setKeydownEvent(e);
});
```

In my map:

```
getCtrlKeyStatus: function(e) {
  var ret = false;
  var global_event = app.getKeydownEvent();

  if (typeof(global_event) === 'object'  && global_event.ctrlKey) {
    ret = true;
  }
  return ret;
},
```